# how to remove duplicate arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I am getting the duplicate array like this:-

```
Array ( [0] => Afghanistan [1] => Albania ) Array ( [0] => Afghanistan [1] => Albania )
```

How I remove the this duplicate array... I want output like this..

```
Array ( [0] => Afghanistan [1] => Albania )
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried in order to solve this

Comment: As it seems like you are outputting the arrays in a loop, so you first would have to create an array an put them all in there, so you could tell if you have duplicates or not

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

For more you can visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: Thanks your solution works. But Now I have to update these values one by one in the table how I do this. I know I have to use foreach loop but I am not getting the results. Thanks.

Comment: @Junaidafzal Add the output you currently get and what you want that both in your question.....

Comment: @Junaidafzal And if possible then approve this as a answer and +vote it. And create new one with new query.